# How to display color swatch on home page slider magento 2

Tags: magento2

i have create custom module for product slider and i am using that module on homepage.
i want to display color swatch on home page , please guide me how to do that.
i am using getProductDetailsHtml($item) method for display swatch images , but this method not working 
Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3solver.com/magento2-color-swatch-on-product-compare-page/ check this link, i used this for showing on product compare page, hope this will help

Comment: sorry i tried your suggested solution but not working , do you any other idea about this issue @arushi

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: yes i solve this